# Is there an extension to this circular contour?

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

If we are given a finite, multivariate series:

$$f(x) = \sum_{j=a}^b{\sum_{k=c}^d{h_{j,k}x^{j+k i}}}$$

where the $h_{j,k}$'s are constants, and $j+k i$ is a complex number, $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are integers, we can attempt to find the coefficient associated with a particular $j$ and $k$.  In other words, we want to separate the term $h_{j,k}x^{j+k i}$ from the function.

We can do this for an integer valued exponent:

$$f(x) = \sum_{j=a}^b{h_j x^j}$$

In complex analysis, this is equivalent to the circular contour:

$$h(-v) = \int_C{ f(x)\cdot x^v dx}$$

We can simply take $x=\text{exp}(i\cdot t) + v\cdot \text{exp}(i\cdot t)$ and integrate $t$ from $-\pi$ to $\pi$:

$$h(-v) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi{f\left(\text{exp}(i\cdot t) + v\cdot \text{exp}(i\cdot t)\right)dt}$$

**The Question**

Can we do this for a two-valued (or complex) exponent, like the one shown at the start of the question?

**A Problem**

I'm aware that we can integrate twice to accomplish this (once for the power of $j$ and a second time for the power of $k$).  However, I'm wondering if it's possible to do this with a single integral.  The reason is that the result from the first integral is really ugly, so I'm hoping to find a way to skip over that step by doing everything in a single integration.  It seems like this may be a one integral problem with hypercomplex numbers.